How can IQ samples be obtained by shifting a signal down to DC?
In a direct sampling architecture where the first Nyquist zone is sampled, how can IQ samples be obtained by downconverting a recorded QPSK-modulated signal to DC? What is the relationship between this downconversion process and the IQ components?

relationship: it is the relationship. The IQ samples are the shifted-down passband signal. That's why we call it equivalent baseband! The result is an IQ signal. You already have all the answers!

Could you please explain the mathematical basis or provide references where I can learn more about this? Specifically, how does this downconversion process result in IQ components that represent the original modulated signal?

What background do you have? For example, for me, this was part of the first few hours of a lecture in communications engineering, so, I'd recommend a standard textbook on that; it's in every single entry-level modern textbook on digital communications (e.g., Kammeyer, Sklar, Proakis, Lapidoth)! That's why I ask for your background: usually, students who already are sitting in a lecture with recommded literature are asking this, and it's usually wisest to refer to the same literature as the lecturer does.

Im an Electrical engineering student.

that's great, was in the same situation myself. Again, if you can, get the textbook your professor recommends with their "basics of communications engineering" lecture. If there's no such textbook, you can probably find Proakis' Digital Communications in your uni library. But as said, any textbook should explain this pretty well: you shift in frequency, giving you complex samples.
